# ZF2 get data from ResultSet

Tags: php, zend-framework2, resultset

I'm doing a raw query on ZF2 `Select * from users` using DbAdaptor and I'm getting an

> object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet...

error that I'm not sure how to parse/convert to data.

Here's my code:

```
public function __construct(Adapter $dbAdapter)
{
    $this->_dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    $query = "Select * from users";
    $resultSet = $this->_dbAdapter->query($query, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
    var_dump($resultSet);
}
```

This returns an object like:

```
object(Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet)#253 (8) {
  ["allowedReturnTypes":protected]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "arrayobject"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "array"
  }
  ["arrayObjectPrototype":protected]=>
  ...
  ...
```

And contains no results from the database, How can I get those results?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($resultSet as $row){
    $row->mycolumn1
    $row->mycolumn2
}
```

OR

```
$resultSet = $resultSet->toArray();
```